# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'writeFile'

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using Ionic framework that at it's heart is AngularJS and I'm trying to save a file to the device's storage. This code works in creating the pdf:

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            var dd = createDocumentDefinition(invoice);
            var pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);

            pdf.getBase64(function (output) {
                resolve(base64ToUint8Array(output));
            });
        });
```

Now I'm trying to save the pdf using:

```
return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                var dd = createDocumentDefinition(invoice);
                var pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);

                //For download Android
                var pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd).getBuffer(function (buffer) {

                var utf8 = new Uint8Array(buffer); // Convert to UTF-8...

                binaryArray = utf8.buffer; // Convert to Binary...


                $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, "example.pdf", binaryArray, true) //This saves to device storage

                .then(function (success) {

                console.log("pdf created");

                }, function (error) {

                console.log("error");

              });

              });
          });
```

The main area the first few lines of converting is where I believe the problem is coming from but I don't seem to be able to fix it, I keet getting whenever the device tries to save:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'writeFile'
```

What is the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the cordova file plugin is installed?  Keep in mind that you need to install the file plugin to use $cordovaFile.  Run the following command in your project directory...

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

Sometimes you will need to remove and re-add the platform that you are building against when you add plugins.  If you add the plugin and still have trouble try to remove and then add the platform

```
cordova platform rm android
ionic platform add android
```

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

Comment: Can you pause the debugger at that line and confirm the object referenced by $cordovaFile?